# listar los archivos de un directorio en web

Tags: php, javascript

estoy usando php y html para mostrar como una galería de archivos, donde el usuario entre y pueda ver que archivos están dentro de una carpeta llamada converted_files que esta en una ruta distinta al código php que estoy usando y el problema es que no me muestran los archivos y en mi localhost también aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven parece que no esta tomando bien las variables $archivo y $contador

```
    <?php
    $directorio = "C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\Codes\Ozone\prueba1\converted_files";        #carpeta con archivos
    $contador = 0;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/css/main.css') }}" />
    
    <title>Mis archivos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Archivos convertidos</h1>
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Tus archivos subidos </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="caja">
        <?php
            $dir = opendir($directorio);
                while ($archivo = readdir($dir)){
                    if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != ".."){           #muestro los archivos mas el contador
                        $contador++;
                        echo  "nombre: <strong> $archivo </strong></br>" ;
                    }
                }
                echo "total de archivos: <strong> $contador </strong></br>" ;
            
            closedir($dir);
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

no se si es necesario usar php o si se podrá con javascript pero todo lo que conseguia de mostrar archivos de una carpeta era en php

Comment: ¿Tu script se llama `gallery`? Si no se llama `gallery.php` o, en general, no tiene extensión `.php` será enviado al navegador sin interpretar.

Answer (score 0):

Hummm creo que la mejor manera  para recorrer los directorios seria con la función glob de php en tu caso seria algo como esto:

```
<?php
$directorio = "C:\Users\pc1\Desktop\Codes\Ozone\prueba1\converted_files";
#carpeta con archivos
$contador = 0;

$archivos = glob("$directorio/*");
introducir el código aquí

foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {   
     echo "nombre: <strong> $archivo </strong></br>" ;
                            }
?>
```

Creo que esta seria la forma mas eficiente de recorrer tu directorio ademas con esta funciona puedes poner filtros como por ejemplo solo imágenes de la siguiente forma asi:

```
glob("$directorio/{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Me comentas si te fue útil la información.